# Sort multiple arrays based on one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of javascript arrays, with each inner array being of equal length. I want to sort one of the inner arrays chronologically (its members are all numbers), and I want the other arrays to re-order in the same way. E.g.

we start with this:

```
[[2, 3, 1], ["deux", "trois", "un"], ["zwei", "drei", "eins"]]
```

and the result I want is:

```
[[1, 2, 3], ["un", "deux", "trois"], ["eins", "zwei", "drei"]]
```

I've tried different variations on the following, but had no luck:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
```

All I get back is exactly what I put in!

Comment: is each of a sub arrays's item unique (at least within its containing array)?

Comment: Good question, no there will likely be multiple instances of the same value in each sub array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get an array of sorted indices and map sorted arrays.

```js
const
    arrays = [[2, 3, 1], ["deux", "trois", "un"], ["zwei", "drei", "eins"]],
    sorted = arrays.map(
        (indices => a => indices.map(i => a[i]))
        ([...arrays[0].keys()].sort((a, b) => arrays[0][a] - arrays[0][b]))
    );

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A function for it.

```js
const
    sortNumbers = (a, b) => a - b,
    sortABC = (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b),
    sortArray = (arrays, index, fn) => {
        const
            source = arrays[index],
            indices = [...source.keys()].sort((a, b) => fn(source[a], source[b]));
        return arrays.map(a => indices.map(i => a[i]));
    },
    arrays = [[2, 3, 1], ["deux", "trois", "un"], ["zwei", "drei", "eins"]],
    sorted0 = sortArray(arrays, 0, sortNumbers),
    sorted1 = sortArray(arrays, 1, sortABC);
    sorted2 = sortArray(arrays, 2, sortABC);

console.log(sorted0);
console.log(sorted1);
console.log(sorted2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Am I wrong to think this does a lot of extra work every time around?

Comment: no just once for the closure over the indices and then it returns new mapped arrays.

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't appear to work for longer length sub-arrays though. Why could that be?

Comment: @Will, it should work for any length. it had a littel mistake by taking the arrays indices instead of the nested array.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, beside the index, the function takes now a function for comparing two values. anway. is it really important?

Comment: @NinaScholz ... looks like it was. Pushing you a little bit might have contributed to you coming up with the last version of the finally accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, we should get the new indexes for array of numbers then apply the same new indexes to non number arrays:

```js
const arrays = [
  [2, 3, 1],
  ["deux", "trois", "un"],
  ["zwei", "drei", "eins"],
];
const [arrNbrs] = arrays;

const newIndexes = [...arrNbrs].sort().map((nbr) => arrNbrs.indexOf(nbr));

const sortedArrays = arrays.map((subArray) =>
  subArray.map((_, index) => subArray[newIndexes[index]])
);

console.log("sortedArrays", sortedArrays);
```

Comment: such terse, very one-liner ;)

Comment: the power of FP pipelines,  they swallow other lines :p

Answer (score 1):

```js
const test = [
  [3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2],
  ["trois", "deux", "un", "trois", "deux", "un", "deux"],
  ["drei", "zwei", "eins", "drei", "zwei", "eins", "zwei"]
];


function sortListsAccordingToReferenceList(
  listOfLists,
  listIndex,
  referenceComparator
) {
  function defaultComparator(a, b) {
    return (
      ((a.localeCompare) && (b.localeCompare))
        ? a.localeCompare(b)
        : (((a < b) && -1) || ((a > b) && 1) || 0)
    );
  }
  const comparator = (typeof referenceComparator === 'function')
    ? referenceComparator
    : defaultComparator;

  function compareReferenceItems(a, b) {
    return comparator(a.value, b.value);
  }
  const referenceList = listOfLists[listIndex];
  const lastIndexList = referenceList.map((item, idx) => ({

    lastIndex: idx,
    value: item

  })).sort(compareReferenceItems).map(referenceItem =>

    referenceItem.lastIndex
  );
  // console.log('lastIndexList : ', lastIndexList);

  // - in case of needing to return the
  //   mutated original array use this block ...
  // 
  // listOfLists.forEach((list, idx) => {
  // 
  //   const duplicates = Array.from(list);
  //   lastIndexList.forEach((lastIndex, idx) => {
  // 
  //     list[idx] = duplicates[lastIndex];
  //   });
  // });
  // return listOfLists; // return mutated original array.

  // - ... otherwise go with pure mappping.
  return listOfLists.map(list =>
    list.map((item, idx) => list[lastIndexList[idx]])
  ); 
}

console.log(
  'sort every array according to numeric sort order ...',
  sortListsAccordingToReferenceList(test, 0)
);
console.log(
  'sort everything by French as lexicographic sort reference ...',
  sortListsAccordingToReferenceList(test, 1)
);
console.log(
  'sort everything by German as lexicographic sort reference ...',
  sortListsAccordingToReferenceList(test, 2)
);

console.log(
  'sort every array according to numeric custom sort order ...',
  sortListsAccordingToReferenceList(test, 0, (a, b) =>
    // comparator function for descending sort order
    (((a > b) && -1) || ((a < b) && 1) || 0)
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a oneliner, but easier to read

```js
let nested = [
  [2, 3, 1],
  ["deux", "trois", "un"],
  ["zwei", "drei", "eins"]
];
let srcArr;
nested = nested.map((arr, i) => {
  if (i === 0) { // the reference
    srcArr = arr.slice(0); // take a copy
    arr.sort((a, b) => a - b); // sort the nested one
    return arr;
  }
  return arr.map((item, i) => arr[
    srcArr.indexOf(nested[0][i]) // return in the order of the reference 
  ]);
})
console.log(nested)
```